# Compute the adjoint of an operator in $L^2[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Consider a bounded linear operator $A:L^2[-1,1]\to L^2[-1,1]$ given by $Af(t)=\int_{-1}^0f(s)ds+(\int_{-1}^1f(s)ds)t^2$.

**Question:** Compute the adjoint of the operator $A$.

I know we need to calculate $\langle Af,g\rangle=\langle f, A^*g\rangle$, but I have troubles of calculating $\langle f, A^*g\rangle$ through the calculation of integral. Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Verify that $\int Af(t)g(t)dt=\int_{-1}^{1} f(t) [ I_{(-1,0)}(t)\int_{-1}^{1}g(s)+\int_{-1}^{1}g(s)s^{2}]ds$. Hence $A^{*}g(t)=I_{(-1,0)}(t)\int_{-1}^{1}g(s)ds+\int_{-1}^{1}g(s)s^{2}ds$.

Here $I_A$ is defined by $I_A(x)=1$ if $x \in A$ and $0$ if $x \notin A$.

Comment: When I calculate the integral, I computed as this. And I don't know how to compute forward. $\langle Af(t)g(t)\rangle=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^0f(s)dsg(t)dt+\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1f(s)dst^2g(t)dt=\int_{-1}^0\int_{-1}^1f(s)g(t)dtds+\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1f(s)t^2g(t)dtds$.

Comment: The idea it to write this as $\int f(s)h(s)ds$ for some function $h$. Note that $\int_{-1}^{0} f(s)ds $ can be written as $\int_{-1}^{1} f(s) I_{(-1,0)}ds $. This is needed to make sure that all your integrals are from $-1$ to $+1$. @delta